# How do you use both Spring Data JPA and Spring Data Elasticsearch repositories on the same domain class in a Spring Boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm trying to use both Spring Data JPA and Spring Data Elasticsearch on the same domain object but it doesn't work.

When I tried to run a simple test, I got the following exception:

> org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No
>   property index found for type Person!     at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.(PropertyPath.java:75)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:327)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:307)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:270)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:241)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.(Part.java:76)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.(PartTree.java:235)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:373)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.(PartTree.java:353)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.(PartTree.java:84)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:61)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.0.RELEASE.jar:na]   at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:95)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.0.RELEASE.jar:na]   at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:206)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.0.RELEASE.jar:na]   at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:73)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.0.RELEASE.jar:na]   at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:408)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:206)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:251)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:237)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.0.RELEASE.jar:na]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]   ... 43 common frames
>   omitted

They work when disabling either one.

The project is based on Spring Boot 1.3.0.M5.

This is a sample project reproducing the situation:

https://github.com/izeye/spring-boot-throwaway-branches/tree/data-jpa-and-elasticsearch

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Repositories in Spring Data are datasource agnostic, meaning that `JpaRepository` and `ElasticsearchRepository` both roll up into `Repository` interface. When this is the case, then auto-configuration of Spring Boot will cause Spring Data JPA to try and configure a bean for each repository in the project that inherits any Spring Data Commons base repository.

To fix this problem you need to move your JPA repository and Elasticsearch repository to separate packages and make sure to annotate your `@SpringBootApplication` application class with:

- `@EnableJpaRepositories`
- `@EnableElasticsearchRepositories`

Then you need to specify where the repositories are for each enable annotation. This ends up looking like:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.izeye.throwaway.data")
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories("com.izeye.throwaway.indexing")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Then your application will be able to disambiguate which repositories are intended for which Spring Data project.

Comment: Thanks for the details. It gave me a hint to a final solution I chose. For me, using `includeFilters` is better than moving them to another packages. Spring Data's datasource-agnostic nature is very nice but it would be nice that Spring Data JPA didn't scan `ElasticsearchRepository` interfaces if possible.

Comment: For someone who interests what I did, see https://github.com/izeye/spring-boot-throwaway-branches/commit/874ccba09189d6ef897bc430c43b6e3705404399

Comment: Thanks kenny-bastani and johnny-lim, I voted up for you both

Answer (score 6):

You can use like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = ElasticsearchCrudRepository.class))
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = ElasticsearchCrudRepository.class))
public class DataConfiguration {
    ...
}
```

Or in SpringBoot:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = ElasticsearchCrudRepository.class))
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = ElasticsearchCrudRepository.class))
public class MyApplication {
    ...
}
```

Comment: It should be in `@EnableJpaRepositories` we should use `JpaRepository.class` right not `ElasticsearchCrudRepository.class`???

Comment: Because i use exlude in `@EnableJpaRepositories`, so. in Jpa Repository, you can use not only `JpaRepository.class`