# Move spring repository to different folder

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-elasticsearch

Is it possible to move spring data repo Implementation to different folder (not same or sub folder of original inteface)? If I have interface and implementation in same folder all works fine. If I move it from e.g `com.app.domain.repo` to `com.app.infrastr.repo`, I get `Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property methodName found for type RepoInterfaceName`.

**UPDATE**

```
import com.app.domain.repo

public interface ARepo extends ElasticsearchRepository<A, String>, CustomizedARepo {
}

public interface CustomizedARepo {
    List<A> makeSearch(int x);
}

import com.app.infrastr.repo

public class CustomizedARepoImpl implements CustomizedARepo {

    private ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate;

    public CustomizedARepoImpl(ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate) {
        this.elasticsearchTemplate = elasticsearchTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public List<A> makeSearch(int x){ return null; }
}
```

And configuration class is

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = {"com.app.domain.repo", "com.app.infrastr.repo"})
public class Config{}
```

Error is:

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property makeSearch found for type ARepo
```

If I move `CustomizedARepoImpl` to `com.app.domain.repo` all works OK.

Comment: Please provide relevant code here to help people answer. There are many possibilities here. My guess is that you have a custom entityManagerFactory() bean that points to the specific package.

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: Based on what you added, I am wondering if you are mixing JPA and ES repositories. Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/32879779/4614870

Comment: @Brian I have no Jpa repos. Only this single Elastic search repo, and its implementation. I don't use spring boot.

Answer (score 0):

I found a reason. It is method `getBasePackages` inside file `RepositoryBeanDefinitionBuilder` in spring-data-commons that makes you have implementation in same folder like this

```
public Iterable<String> getBasePackages() {
            return Collections.singleton(ClassUtils.getPackageName(fragmentInterfaceName));
        }
```

If i change this to

```
public Iterable<String> getBasePackages() {
            return configuration.getBasePackages();
        }
```

everything works as expected. Will check why the guys from spring did it this way...